# 'function' object has no attribute 'name' when registering blueprint

Tags: python, flask

Here is my project layout:

```
baseflask/
   baseflask/
      __init__.py
      views.py
      resources/
          health.py/
   wsgi.py/
```

Here is my print

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import Response
health = Blueprint('health', __name__)
@health.route("/health", methods=["GET"])
def health():
    jd = {'status': 'OK'}
    data = json.dumps(jd)
    resp = Response(data, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    return resp
```

How I register in `__init__.py`:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

CORS(app)

from baseflask.health import health
app.register_blueprint(health)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/baseflask/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
    from baseflask import app
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/baseflask/baseflask/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    app.register_blueprint(health)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 62, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in register_blueprint
    if blueprint.name in self.blueprints:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Note that the error you made is not specific to Flask or its blueprints. However, if you think the documentation needs improvement, by all means engage with the project constructively via the project's [issues page](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You **masked** the `health` global name referring to `Blueprint` instance, by re-using the name for the view function:

```
health = Blueprint('health', __name__)
@health.route("/health", methods=["GET"])
def health():
```

You can't have both the route view function and the blueprint use the same name; you replaced the global name `health` that referred to the blueprint and are trying to register the route function for the same global name.

Use a different name for the blueprint:

```
health_blueprint = Blueprint('health', __name__)
```

and register that:

```
from baseflask.health import health_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(health_blueprint)
```

or use a different name for the view function (at which point the endpoint name changes too unless you explicitly use `endpoint='health'` in the `@health.route(...)` decorator).

Comment: In flask1.0 there is no problem if these are same name.

Comment: @gold-kou: it's the *name of the globals* that is an issue. After `health = Blueprint`, `def health` rebinds the name `health` to the route view function. You now cannot use `health` to refer to the blueprint object anymore. That's an issue in any version of Flask.

Answer (score 10):

```
health = Blueprint('health', __name__)
@health.route("/health", methods=["GET"])
def health():
```

Your blueprint name is same with your function name, try to rename the function name instead.

```
health = Blueprint('health', __name__)
@health.route("/health", methods=["GET"])
def check_health():
```

Comment: thanks pal, Flask v 2.0.x , use another name for the function, don't use the same blueprint name.